# Highlighting divs while scrolling with arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i've been stuck on this problem for a little while. Here is what im working with right now (a quick mock up). [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/coconnor/2UALk/2/)

I can get the thing to scroll and highlight the selected notes (and click on them), but the scroll bar is faster than the arrow scrolling. Does anyone know how to slow it down, or speed up the arrows. Or am i going about this the wrong way.

Thanks for any help in advance